# How do I begin to diagnose and fix indicator-datetime-service using 100% CPU and 90+% memory in 16.10?

Tags: indicator, 16.10

The high usage starts immediately after boot, pauses for 2-3 seconds every minute or so but otherwise uses the resources to the extent that the computer is useless. I can get my system back temporarily by issuing a `killall unity-panel-service` but that comes with some usability overhead and isn't a solution.

Comment: What happens if your set the time&date settings to manually update the time, instead of auto from the Internet?

Comment: @heynnema  No effect

Comment: What happens if you log into the Guest account, instead of your normal account?

Comment: @heynnema Everything seems normal under guest.

Comment: Ah! A clue! Possibly something in your own account is causing the problem. Did you make any changes to .profile, or .bashrc, or any other dot files? Or add a startup application that's causing the problem?

Comment: @heynnema I don't think so, I have never knowingly touched them and as far as I remember I was just working along last night, put it to sleep, woke up this morning banged around in gnucash for a while, went back later and it was "frozen".  Actually just mostly with tiny amounts of CPU available every few minutes.

Comment: Have you rebooted your machine since this problem started? Otherwise, I'd temporarily turn off startup apps, log out, log in, and see if the problem gets fixed.

Comment: @heynnema, had rebooted several times trying different things, in startup I decided to take one at a time, most obvious was calendar indicator which I turned off. Logout / login and it seems ok, oddly nothing changed visually in my clock/calendar indicator. I'll keep an eye on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

Everything appears to work properly in the Guest account.

Possibility that something in the primary user's account is causing the problem. Suggest that they temporarily disable some Startup Applications to see if that fixes the problem.

User disabled a clock/calendar indicator, and so far, it's all running good.

Comment: As I can't replicate it and I was trying several things listed in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-datetime/+bug/1642634 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-datetime/+bug/1652789 I'm still not %100 sure of the answer. But since I was trying things one at a time, rebooting in between, monitoring closely and this is was the last thing that happened before the problem went away I'm going to accept it.

Answer (score 6):

This happened to me on Ubuntu 17.10. The cause of the problem for me was that the evolution data server was trying to sync with Google calendar events and somehow caused a memory leak.

Before doing anything, you may need to stop the indicator datetime service temporarily to get your computer in a usable state. Here's how:

1. Open up System Monitor
2. Sort services by the highest CPU or Memory consumption
3. indicator datetime service should show up at the top
4. Right click on it and select stop process.

Now we need to disable the Google calendar sync.

Here's how to do it:

1. Open up Calendar
2. From the menu, select calendar > Calendars
3. From online accounts, select Google (or maybe it's another one for you)
4. Disable calendar sync for the online account

I actually just removed the online account entirely and when I rebooted the problem was gone. Hope this helps.

A clue on how to solve this is [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-datetime/+bug/1652789/comments/4).
[Here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-datetime/+bug/1652789)'s the full bug report.

Comment: Having the same error in 18.04 right after logging into my Google Account. Searching for "datetime memory usage" brought me here.

Comment: Just happened to me today on 18.04. To the point that indicator-datetime-service was using 11GB RAM and frozen the entire system.